# Wildcard % operator not working on bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, wildcard

On Bigquery, am trying to select WHERE item IN ('%xxxxxxxxxx', '%xxxxxxxxxx'). However when I pull that it doesn't return any results. However if I get rid of the wildcard % it does return results. Am I using the wrong wildcard operator here?

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `LIKE` operator instead. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM UNNEST(['%pattern1', '%pattern2']) AS pattern
  WHERE item LIKE pattern
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sending! How would you do this in Legacy SQL though? My query is all in legacy.

Comment: Is there a reason to use legacy SQL for your query? The BigQuery team recommends using standard SQL if you can, since that is the only implementation under active development. If you need help changing parts of the query to use standard SQL instead, you can refer to the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(item, r'xxxxxxxxxx$|yyyyyyyy$')
```

You can play with it with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST(['a_item', 'b_item', 'a_piece', 'b_piece', 'a_part', 'b_part']) AS item
)
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(item, r'item$|part$')
```

See more about [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains)